# How do I replace numbers in specific field bash

Tags: bash, unix, sed, freebsd, find-and-replace

I am using FreeBSD 3.2-RELEASE.
For example output from `last`-

```
abelovsk14 1 10-7 22:06
adamov14 5 10-5 22:53
almasi14 1 10-8 22:56
anda13 53 10-6 22:16
andrejko14 51 10-7 01:28
```

Is possible to replace `$4` field to this-

```
abelovsk14 1 10-07 22:06
adamov14 5 10-05 22:53
almasi14 1 10-08 22:56
anda13 53 10-06 22:16
andrejko14 51 10-07 01:28
```

`$4` field are days. I want to replace day with value for example -`1` to value `01`
Is possible to do this with `sed` or `awk` ?

```
1-01
2-02
3-03
..
9-09
10-10
..
```

- info-abelovsk14(user) 1(numberofnightlogintoserver) 10(month)-7(day)
  22:06(lastnightlogin)*

Comment: _"Is possible to do this with sed or awk ?"_  Yes, it is possible with either.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i tried but not sucessfull.

Comment: You have an unusual way of counting.  I would have said that the date is the ***3rd*** field (the time is the 4th).

Comment: @G-Man ou yes that is true my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
last | sed 's/^\(.* [0-9][0-9]* \)\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9]\) /\1\2-0\3 /'
```

It's difficult to explain `sed` commands, but basically:

It looks at the beginning of the line for something followed by a space, then it matches on one or more numbers (the second column), then by matching a date matching MM-d followed by a space. It then prints them back out with a zero inserted before the single digit day.

Comment: Okey that's solved the problem.
I have question what means `^\(.* [0-9][0-9]* \)` - in the bracket is something like a store value ?
`/\1\2-0\3 /` - stored values and print order ?
`\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9]\)`- something like a `grep` ?

Comment: That first group you mentioned `\(.* [0-9][0-9]* \)` is used by `\1` in the result. Each grouping formed by parentheses `\(\)` produces a numbered group we can access like `\1` or `\2`. There are many good sites for learning how to write regular expressions. [This one looks promising](http://regexone.com). There are some differences between a typical regex and the kind that `sed` uses, but most of it is the same!

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
last | sed 's/^\(\s*\S\+\s\+\S\+\s\+[0-9]\+-\)\([0-9]\s.*\)$/\10\2/'
```

P.D.: I'm using Linux.

Comment: don't work, what actually do your code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
last | sed 's/-\([1-9]\)\>/-0\1/'
```

It looks for a digit 1 to 9 preceeded by hyphen and followed by word delimiter, captures digit, replaces with hyphen, zero, digit.

Comment: Beware: having user names like **salvo-7** may cause unwanted results